# package installed, but not found when knitting

Tags: r, knitr, packrat

Can anyone suggest troubleshooting tips for the case where you can load a package from the console, but not when knitting?

I have a project in RStudio that uses Packrat. The package I want to load is installed and registered in Packrat. I can load it from the console, but when I try to knit I get the error:

> Error in library(Rmisc) : there is no package called 'Rmisc'

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5    tools_3.3.2     yaml_2.1.14     stringi_1.1.5   knitr_1.17      stringr_1.2.0  
[7] packrat_0.4.6-9 evaluate_0.10.1
```

Comment: This feels like a local issue, but I've restarted, cleared the cache, updated RStudio from a previous dev version to the current release with no luck.

Comment: Removing packrat solves the problem. Might be a git-packrat issue.